# A question on the scope of local variables when using the Let expression during a recursive function call

Tags: recursion, ml

I am having some troubles trying to figure out the current dynamic environment during a recursive call to a function and values  the local variables in the function are bound to .This is not just a problem I am facing in ML but even in JAVA, I get very confused about the scopes of variables during recursive calls.

```
fun examplefunction(x:int,ys:int list)=
if null (tl ys)
then 0
else
let
  val temp=0
  val temp=temp +(hd ys)
  val tail= (tl ys)
  val k=1
in

  if x>temp andalso temp+(hd tail)>=x

  then k

  else k+examplefunction(x,tl ys)

end
```

I am having a hard time understanding how the temp variable gets updated during the recursive call(if I assume the input int list is large enough). For example in the case

x=5 and ys=[2,1,3] and I call the function by

examplefunction(5,[2,1,3]);

In this case (tl ys) in line 2 is not null

and hence else gets executed and in line 6 the variable temp gets bound to the integer 0, in the subsequent line 7 it gets shadowed and in the new dynamic enviroment it gets bound to 2. The variable tail is bound to the int list [1] and the variable k is bound to 1.

Now in "in" (starting line 10) the expression in if on line 12 is false so the else in line 16 is executed which recursively calls the function

examplefunction(5,[1,3])

I want to understand which enviroment is this function call "examplefunction(5,[1,3])"?

When this recursive function call gets excecutes then in line 6 does the temp variable which was 2 in the previous call get shadowed by 0 and then subsequently by 0+hd [1,3]=0+1=1 .

This is extremely confusing for me and really a big roadblock in writing some functions in the homework assigment. Please do let me know if the question isnt clear.

Comment: The most important thing to learn about recursive functions is that they work exactly like non-recursive functions. Each function call has its own unique set of local variables, and nothing gets "updated" during the recursive call.

Comment: so in the second call the variable temp will be bound to 0 again in the  new dynamic environment instead of 2?

Comment: "It" doesn't get bound again - that function call has a different local binding with the same name. That binding "disappears" when the function returns.

Comment: You can replace each binding with its definition and get an equivalent function but without any local bindings. That might make it clearer that there is no "updating" going on.

Answer (score 0):

An environment associates names, like the arguments of the function x, ys, and those in the body of the let clause, temp, tail, and k (in this case). Each val declaration inside the let extends the environment, binding a name to a subexpression.

So looking at examplefunction, the environment in which the body of the function is evaluated has x and ys bound to whatever the function was called with. In your first example that is: x is bound to 5 and ys is bound to [2,1,3].

When evaluating the if branch and the then branch, nothing is added to the environment. In the else branch, there is a let clause, which will add some new bindings to the environment.

The first is temp = 0. At this point in the expression, the evaluation environment as x, ys, and now temp.

Next, temp is rebound to the subexpression temp + hd ys. At this point, environment won't have any new names bound, but the expression to which temp is bound has changed.

The next binding in the let clause is tail to tl ys. This adds a new name to the environment, tail.

Finally, k is bound to 1. The environment now has variables x, ys, temp, tail, and k bound to some subexpressions. When called with arguments x = 5 and ys = [2,1,3], these bindings will be: temp = 0 + hd ys = 2, tail = tl ys = [1,3], and k = 1.

The next if-then-else subexpression is then evaluated, and examplefunction may or may not be called recursively depending on if the boolean x>temp andalso temp+(hd tail)>=x evaluates to true or not.

What's important is that if it does get called recursively, the environment won't have temp, tail, and k bound as they are local to the let clause. As written, x will be bound to x and ys to tl ys in the recursive call, and we start the same process over again.

Key points:

1. Environment associates names to expressions.
2. Arguments of functions and val declarations in let clauses add local bindings to the environment during evaluation of expressions.
3. When the function is called recursively, whatever was bound inside the let  expression inside the function body will not be bound to start in the recursive call